# DevExpress master detail row cell style

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, master-detail

I want to changing my gridview's master detail rows style according to some conditoion. My code like this ;

```
        GridView newDetailView = grdLog.CreateView("GridView") as GridView;
        GridView View = sender as GridView;
        gvLog.MasterRowGetLevelDefaultView += (s, e2) =>
        {
            if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gvLog.Columns.Count - 15; i++)
                {
                    string strTimeKey1 = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns[i]);
                    string strTimeKey2 = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(View.FocusedRowHandle, View.Columns[i]);
                    if (!strTimeKey1.Equals(strTimeKey2))
                    {
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }

            }
        };
```

My parent row and detail row have same columns , It must be like If detail row' column value is different from parent row's column value , cell color will be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From:[How To Dynamically Format Columns For A Detail View](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q248641/how-to-dynamically-format-columns-for-a-detail-view)

> Columns are already created, when the [MasterRowExpanded](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_MasterRowExpandedtopic) event
>   occurs. Please try to use this event to customize them as you require,
>   and let me know whether this solution meets your needs.

Refer these DevExpress threads:
[Style conditions conditional formatting for master and detail views](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q504781/master-detail-grid-with-styleformatcondition)
[How to set row style of Detail grid records after data binded to xtragrid master-detail data](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T327391/how-to-set-row-style-of-detail-grid-records-after-data-binded-to-xtragrid-master-detail)
[Master/Detail grid with StyleFormatCondition](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q504781/master-detail-grid-with-styleformatcondition)

Comment: Thank you. I will try them . @NiranjanKala